# Defacing a downclosed post

Tags: discussion

I'm curious what the right response is to the situation where a post gets downclosed, and then the OP defaces it. For example,

- [Complexity of finding a hamiltonian circuit in a Great Rhombicuboctahedral graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/869507/8348) (the post is now deleted.)

---

For the <10K users, the post linked to above went from this:

> [image: Before defacement]

to this:

> [image: After defacement]

Comment: Flag a mod. Just let us know that the post was defaced.

Comment: What exactly does "downclosed" mean?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche *downvoted and closed*

Comment: That was not defacing, it was asking for help. Sort of what the site is about.

Comment: @AndréNicolas No. To ask for help, one can add the same mention at the beginning of the post.

Comment: @Joel: Also "upen", "upleted", "downceptted" (for answers) and who can forget "downleted".

Comment: @AsafKaragila Don't forget "downpen" and "flagpen" :P

Comment: @JChau: You mean "flappen".

Answer (score 20):

I think the comment by robjohn applies to malicious defacement, but this case falls into another group: OP wants to delete their unanswered question but does not know how. In such a case, I would

1. Rollback, to maintain professional appearance of the site's front page.
2. ...
3. (okay, you can stop laughing now)
4. Inform the OP that there is a *delete* button just under the post, to the left.

Note that *unregistered* users can't delete own posts. If the user is unregistered, fall back on flagging  for mod's attention.